# Help with a template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working with/learning template function specialization rules. I start with this function

```
template<typename T>
std::string toString(const T& t)
{
    ostringstream out;
    out << t;
    return out.str();
}
```

Now I'd like to specialize it for const char*

```
typedef const char* ccharPtr;

template<>
std::string toString(const ccharPtr& s)
{
    cout << "in specialization" << endl; // just to let me know
    return std::string(s);
}
```

I'd like to do that without a typedef, but so far I can't figure it out.

That specialization works for a const char*, but not for a char*.

```
const char* s1 = "Hi"
cout << toString(s1); // works
char s2[] = "There";
cout << toString(s2); // doesn't work, since s2 isn't const char*
cout << toString(", Bob"); // doesn't work. Why not?
```

I'd like a single specialization to work for each case, but having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 7):

Why specialise? Just overload the function. Fully specialising function templates is usually not required.

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(const T& in)
{
    ostringstream out;
    out << in;
    return out.str();
}

std::string toString(char const* in)
{
    return in;
}
```

---

OK, if you *really* want to do this, then you have to consider that the type of string literals — although they implicitly *convert* to `char const*` — is `char const[N]`.

```
template <typename T>
std::string toString(T const & t) {
    ostringstream out;
    out << t;
    return out.str();
}

template <>
std::string toString(char const* const & s) {
    cout << "(S1)";
    return std::string(s);
}

template <size_t N>
std::string toString(char (&s)[N]) {
    cout << "(S2)";
    return std::string(s);
}

template <size_t N>
std::string toString(char const (&s)[N]) {
    cout << "(S3)";
    return std::string(s);
}

int main() {
    const char* s1 = "Hi";
    cout << toString(s1) << endl;
    char s2[] = "There";
    cout << toString(s2) << endl;
    cout << toString(", Bob") << endl;
}

// Output:
// (S1)Hi
// (S2)There
// (S3), Bob
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/gLz0x6Vy)

You can omit specialisation `S2`, and then both `"There"` and `", Bob"` will use `S3`.

Be warned that, actually, **this isn't specialisation at all**. I've rather cheated by creating *new* function templates. But I had to to get the `size_t` parameter in; you could only do *real* specialisation here if you picked *one* value for `N` and wrote it into the function signature as part of a concrete type, or if you could *partially* specialise function templates.

Comment: passing a string literal, then it deduces to an array type, which does not match a pointer type (this is specialization, so the types have to match exactly). With the overloading you show, it will use the second `toString`, because the conversion sequences will be ambiguous, but the second one is a non-template, and thus wins.

Comment: @Tomalak: Have I understood it correctly: You are writing `const` after `T` (first template function `std::string toString(T const & t)`), to make the reference const, in cases where T is a pointer?

Comment: @Christian: That's right. For a specialisation, the arguments have to match; so I choose `char const*` for `T` and the result is `char const* const&`, presenting a valid specialisation.

Answer (score 6):

The reason it doesn't work is because it's not actually the right type. String literals are not of type `const char*`, they are of type `const char[N]`. When you pass a string literal, then T is deduced to be `char[N]`. This is an exact match and the specialization is not. You cannot speciailize for string literals, as that would require a partial spec and C++ does not support partial function specializations.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
template <typename T>
    std::string to_string(const T &)
{
    ...
}

// non templated
std::string to_string(const char* x)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes,it will work, but I'm wanting to study template specialization. This is kind of a contrived case, I know.

Comment: So I guess you may have to specialize once for const char* and once for char*. As char* is not const char*, I guess C++ don't match the specialization and use the more generic function. If you want both const char* and char* use the same specialization, I think you have to cast explicitely you parameter from char* to const char*.

Comment: @John: One of the first things you should learn about template specialization is that function template specialization is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Sun Studio C++ compiler.

At first, I used two array overloads (`char (&)[N]` with and without `const`) and two pointer overloads (`char*` and `const char*`).

To my surprise for calls like `toString("quoted literal")` the `const char*` was used and it seemed impossible to force the compiler to choose the array overload. What is even more interesting - for arguments like `char lit[] = "literal"`, `toString(lit)` chose the array overload!

After some thought, I found a way to have a code which *behaves* as partial function specializations. The trick is to make use of SFINAE

First, define a template to distinguish `(const) char*` from `(const) char[N]`

```
template<typename T>
    struct is_literal {
};

template<size_t N>
struct is_literal<const char[N]> {
    typedef std::string type;
    static const size_t len = N - 1;  // subtract terminating null char from N
};

template<size_t N>
struct is_literal<char[N]> {
    typedef std::string type;
    static const size_t len = N - 1;
};

template<>
struct is_literal<const char*> {
    typedef std::string ptr_type;
};

template<>
struct is_literal<char*> {
    typedef std::string ptr_type;
};
```

Inner typedef `type` acts like `enable_if` and `ptr_type` like `disable_if`

We can use `is_literal` to implement the functions:

```
template<typename T>
typename is_literal<T>::type
toString(T& arg)
{
    std::cout << "(literal)";
    // note the second argument which means length
    // this can be a performance gain because no strlen call is needed
    return std::string(arg, is_literal<T>::len); 
}

template<typename T>
typename is_literal<T>::ptr_type
toString(T& arg)
{
    std::cout << "(raw pointer)";
    return std::string(arg);
}
```

Some compilers may have problems with `const` - for those `const T& arg` overloads might be needed.

I use this solution mainly for performance reasons when I have frequently called functions and want to save `strlen` calls or replace `strcpy` with simple `memcpy`