# Program fails to call the specialized template implementation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to learn C++ template. While I run the following example, the program couldn't call the specialized template implementation. Therefore, I got the wrong output. Could anybody tell why?

```
template <class T>
T max(T a, T b)
{
    cout << "2 ..." <<endl;
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
template<>
char* max(char* a, char* b)
{
    cout << "1 ..." <<endl;
    return strcmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
int main()
{
    cout << max("Aladdin", "Jasmine") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `const char* max(const char* a, const char* b)` for the specialization.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem. But why? What are other cases I need to add const key word for template specialization?

Comment: You probably should use `const` in general, if you don't plan to apply changes to the parameters.

Comment: Because a string literal is an array of `const char`, and passing it as a non-`const` pointer will (after conversions) treat it as non-`const`.   The template function is therefore a better match.

Answer (score 2):

The arguments are passed as constant char. Therefore, try the following code instead. Note that I also included the necessary header file includes. Moreover, it is highly advisable to use `std::cout`, or use `using std::cout;`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 

template <class T> 
T max(T a, T b) 
{ 
    std::cout << "2 ..." << std::endl; 
    return a > b ? a : b; 
} 

template<> 
const char* max(const char* a, const char* b) 
{ 
    std::cout << "1 ..." << std::endl; 
    return std::strcmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b; 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << max("Aladdin", "Jasmine") << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing the issue is that the arguments you're passing are of type `char const *` (also can be spelled `const char *`). There isn't any standard way that I know of in C++ to print out the full name of a type. But there is a way to test this sort of thing..

One of the problems of templates is that the system will expand any templates it can. And so you will have code mysteriously work a certain way and not be completely sure why. One way you could've gotten the compiler to tell you exactly what the problem was in this case was to try to remove the template:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using ::std::cout;
using ::std::strcmp;

char* max(char* a, char* b)
{
    cout << "1 ..." << '\n'; // Don't use ::std::endl Use cerr if you need flushing.
    return strcmp(a, b) > 0 ? a : b;
}
int main()
{
    cout << max("Aladdin", "Jasmine") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler would've helpfully told you that you were trying to call a function that took non-const arguments with const arguments, and you would've  learned exactly what the problem was.

Comment: The answers to an [earlier question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6808932/425458) seem to suggest that this kind of specialization can't be done. Basically, the claim was that string literals are really of type `const char[N]`, and so you were unable to specialize without hardcoding a specific value of `N` into the template. That thread was from 2011, so did something change in the more recent cpp standards to make this "just work"? Do you happen to know?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with `std::endl`? Is `'\n'` considered portable now?

Comment: @tel I believe the case you link to is substantially different because the argument is passed by reference. However in this question the argument is passed by value, so the array-to-pointer conversion is applied as part of template argument deduction.

Comment: `<< std::endl` is equivalent to `<< '\n' << std::flush` and the flush is redundant in most cases

Comment: @tel - `'\n'` has _always_ been portable.

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. `std::endl` does indeed always resolve to `'\n'`, but when you're streaming to/from a file `'\n'` will get transparently converted to/from the platform specific line break. Unless you're reading/writing in binary mode. Then you have to be real careful.

Comment: @tel - Yes, and if you're reading/writing in binary mode, `::std::endl` won't help you.